# Hive Query Control Flow?

Tags: hadoop, hive

What is the control flow of a hive query ?

Let's Say, I would like to join Emp_Table with Dept_Table,

How does the flow goes ?

From which table in the meta store, it fetches all relevant informations ?

Such as, 
1) Where is the file that corresponds to Emp_Table ? (HDFS Location)
2) What are the names of fields of table Emp_Table ?
3) What is the delimiter in the file that contains the data of Emp_Table ?
4) How about the data is bucketed or partitioned, in that case from where (Meta Store Table Name) and how (Query) that gives the HDFS Folder locations ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flow goes like this :

Step 1 :
A Hive client triggers a query(CLI or some external client using JDBC, ODBC or Thrift or webUI).

Step 2 :
Compiler receives the query and connects to the metastore.

Step 3:
Start of the compilation phase.

```
Parser
```

Converts the query into `parse tree` representation. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is used to generate the `abstract syntax tree(AST)`.

```
Semantic analyzer
```

The compiler builds a logical plan based on the information provided by the metastore on the input and output tables. The compiler also checks `type compatibilities` and notifies about `compile-time semantic errors` at this stage.

```
QBT creation
```

In this step transformation of AST into an intermediate representation takes place, called as `query block(QB) tree`.

```
Logical plan generator
```

At this step compiler writes the logical plan from the semantic analyzer into a logical tree of operations.

```
Optimization
```

This is the heaviest part of compilation phase as the entire series of `DAG optimizations` take place in this phase. It involves following tasks :

```
Logical optimization

Column pruning

Predicate pushdown

Partition pruning

Join optimization

Grouping(and regrouping)

Repartitioning

Conversion of logical plan into physical plan by physical plan generator

Creation of final DAG workflow of MapReduce by physical plan generator
```

Step 4:
Execution engine gets the compiler outputs to execute them on the Hadoop platform. It involves following tasks :

> A MapReduce task first serializes its part of the plan into a plan.xml
>   file.
>
> plan.xml file is then added to the job cache for the task and the
>   instances of ExecMapper and ExecReducer are spawned using Hadoop.
>
> Each of these classes deserializes the plan.xml file and executes the
>   relevant part of the task.
>
> The final results are stored in a temporary location and at the
>   completion of the entire query the results are moved to the table if
>   it was inserts or partitions. Otherwise returned to the calling
>   program at a temporary location.
>
> Note : All the tasks are executed in the order of their dependencies.
>   Each is only executed if all of its prerequisites have been executed.

And to know about the metastore tables and their fields you can have a look at the MR diagram for metastore :

[image]

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot, That was informative, 
BUT what I am looking for is a way to access the meta store, and fetch out the files corresponding to a table.

Is there any way to get or see plan.xml ?

Comment: Go to your "mapred.local.dir"(or to "hadoop.tmp.dir" if you haven't set this) and browse to "/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache" directory. Here you'll find a directory corresponding to each Hive query MR job. Keep going inside the sub-directories in it and you'll get the xml file. And to see files corresponding to a table you don't have to go to the metastore. You could use "EXPLAIN extended" and it'll show you everything. Look for " Path -> Alias:" and "Path -> Partition:"..HTH

Comment: @Tariq +1 for the concise answer. Note: please name the source: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0124058914

Comment: @LorandBendig : Thank you. In that case I would point out to the paper published by the Facebook Data Infrastructure Team. It was the first text which actually showed me the actual query execution flow. I saw this book at a later stage. Anyways, I got the point :)..So here is the link to that paper : http://i.stanford.edu/~ragho/hive-icde2010.pdf

Answer (score 0):

To see underlaying HDFS directory path, delimiters, partition and other details..

```
describe extended Emp_Table;
describe extended Dept_Table;
```

To See How Hive control flow put `EXPLAIN` or `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` in front of your query.